# fetch client machine specifications like ram, hard disk , .NET version using web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ram

I am a .NET developer, I have a requirement where i need to access the system specifications of client  machine like RAM, Harddisk, third party software installed or not, .NET framework installed. I tried doing it using .net system registry, but i am getting the server values because the code is hosted in server and , i want the client value. I am doing it in web application

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Silverlight application can do this.